# Is referencing files in database for search a good idea?

Tags: php, mysql

Hi I'm working on a file system where people can upload files.

I plan on implementing something like a tag system and other parameters (when it was last opened etc.) to help improve search queries.

I've heard that having references to database is a bad idea. However the other option would be to manually look into a .text file containing its info and i believe that that would drastically slow down speed.

So where should I store parameters that can help aid search?

Comment: if ur database and file system stay consistent, there is no problem with the database aproach.

Comment: i think you may be confusing storing files in the db, which it sounds like you dont plan to do

Comment: There's nothing wrong with storing file meta information in a database, and often it is the only performant solution. Otherwise you would constantly be requerying the file objects to get their last modified times, etc. The only thing you need to worry about is keeping consistency. If perfect consistency is not required, this could be as simple as running a once-per-day job that refreshes all the meta info in the db for each tracked file. If perfect consistency is required, ideally you could have a single portal where users access the files and the portal updates the meta info.

Comment: Since the files are uploaded, another option is to *never update a meta-information record*, but only extract the information once. This ensures perfect consistently - because the file contents cannot be changed (a new upload is simply a new file) and thus the immutable record never gets 'stale'. In this case the 'reference to the file' used in the database might be the SHA-x of the file contents. The 'when was it lasted opened' bit, assuming this does not look at the FS itself, can be handled at the application layer and isn't *file* (aka uploaded content) meta-data.